# Flutter doesn't return any data from PHP API, but browser, postman and cliente made in PHP/Curl does

Tags: php, flutter, http, get

As the title suggests, my problem is with Flutter 3.16.3 and http: ^1.1.2 - I'm using: Windows 11 - Developing for Android, VSCode.

My code in Flutter that doesn't continue beyond the `final response` line is this:

```dart
Future<Users> fetchUsers() async {
     Map<String, String> baseHeader = {
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       // 'Authorization': '<token>'
     };
    
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse('http://apiclbrb.test/login/controller/get_all_users_sem_auth'),
          headers: baseHeader);
    
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
```

I made the API in PHP returning a JSON.

Then the API made in PHP returns the data:

1. In the Browser by directly typing the API URL;
2. At Postman;
3. In a client application made with PHP/Curl;
4. Only in Flutter it doesn't work.

Anyway, **what do I need to define in Flutter or in the PHP API for both to talk? I hope someone has already experienced this.**

Comment: What exception do you get if you wrap the `http.get` in a `try-catch` block? Maybe your settings does not allow http connection, only https.

Comment: The baseHeader appears to be a server response header and does not seem to be correct, although the error you are encountering does not seem to be related to any of the code. try to do the get without the header.

Comment: You are sharing the fetchAlbum code and the error says get_all_users_sem_auth, are you sure you are looking in the right place? 

One piece of advice: go outside for 15 minutes, play with a ball to unblock your mind, and then go back to review the code. :)

Comment: Franklin, Thank you. Yes I have a typo on that line where I fetch fetchAlbum() instead fetchUsers(), but this is just the name of the function, as I've got the same name in the called code, I was to able to enter in the function. I post the real problem bellow and it was the wrong URI. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Hello Peter and thank you, but the header is fine, I put the solution bellow. Anyway thank you.

Comment: None of those allowAccess... headers make _any_ sense in a _request_ ...they are _response_ headers to control CORS functionality. If the _client_ could legitimately set those headers, then CORS would be completely pointless. Please learn how CORS actually works and what those headers are actually for - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for an excellent introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Even so, I won't delete the question because a colleague may go through the same thing.

The problem was the URL. As good as this sounds, it was a url.

When I took the URL and put it in the browser or in Postman or in the client application that uses Curl, everyone was using the format given by laragon, which is: http://apiclbrb.test/login/controller/get_all_users_sem_auth and I believe that this It will be like this with xamp or any other web dev environment with PHP.

When I used this URL and put it into Flutter, nothing happened. So I changed the URL to: http://192.168.18.2/apiclbrb/login/controller/get_all_users_sem_auth/

with ipconfig, I saw the IPv4 address of my machine and voilà, problem solved, see the data appearing in Flutter:

[Flutter returning the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brfi7.png)

I hope it is of value to someone. A hug to everyone. Issue resolved. I just don't know how to mark it as resolved yet.
​

Comment: So basically the device on which Flutter ran doesn't know the DNS name of the server, is the conclusion there.